# In which lifecycle method should I place the materialize dropdown menu initializer in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, materialize

[image: from the materialize css docs. dropdown.html]

As you can see in the materialize docs, using this on a plain html file is quite simple: paste the html somewhere in the body, and paste the js initializer on a script tag. It works fine.

I'm wondering how I can use this on a vue component? I'm talking a `.vue` file with template, script, style sections.

Answer (score 2):

You could try and call this code in one of Vue's [lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks) (see [this diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) to find out where exactly they're executed), you'll probably want to use `mounted`.

But keep in mind this isn't really a bulletproof solution. Vue may manipulate the DOM in different ways later and as such isn't necessarily compatible with Materialize. The best solution in these cases is always to find a framework-specific implementation of the components you're trying to use, e.g. [Vue Material](https://vuematerial.io/).

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong but pastingthe js code inside the `mounted` method doesn't work. But you're right, It's probably easier to go for a something like Vue Material. Appreciate the pointer.

Comment: Yes Vue Mounter is very good alternative working. Just try you find a new for yourself !! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to include initialize function to `mounted() {...}` section of a `.vue` single file component to make sure all HTML tags already exist.